# The mitzvah of mezuzah doesn't commemorate the Korban Pesach?

Tags: mezuzah, korban-pesach

It is very hard to miss the obvious connection between the mitzvah of mezuzah and the blood of the Korban Pesach. Yet, I am not aware of any major sources directly connecting the two.

In contrast, regarding tefillin (where the connection is much less obvious) we find a whole parsha in the Torah connecting them.

Am I missing something? Where can I find related discussion about this topic?

Comment: It's hard to miss the connection between blood on the lintel to protect the firstborn and red lentils traded for a birthright.

Comment: I don't get your point. Do you need a source that explicitly says that we put the mezuzah to commemorate the Exodus? (Otherwise you obviously have [Shemot 12:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.7).)

Comment: https://ohr.edu/7964

Comment: @Kazibácsi: exactly, or an explanation for the absence of it. Torah is אש שחורה על גבי אש לבנה, even the unspoken obvious things are supposed to contain messages.

Comment: A follow up would be "if there are things which are explicitly described reminders of the exodus which seem unrelated to it, why wouldn't mezuzah, which on some level is more than reminiscent of an element of the Exodus, be explicitly called a reminder?"